# Rowfilter by month type

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to use rowfilter in C# but i keep getting an error when trying to filter by month.

The format of the source file is 12/1/2012 16:30 and so on, but i would just like to capture all the entries that fall into a specific month.

How would i do this?

my code is:

```
dvjan.RowFilter = "[Status]='Closed' and [Req Start Date]='January'";
```

Error is:

> Cannot perform '=' operation on System.DateTime and System.String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing the value of a date field with literal text `[Req Start Date]='January'"` and you need to compare to one or more date values instead, like `[Req Start Date] >= '1/1/2012' and [Req Start Date] < '2/1/2012'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guess:

```
dvjan.RowFilter = "[Status]='Closed' and datename(month, [Req Start Date])='January'";
```

This is using the SQL Server syntax for extracting the name of the month, for comparison purpsoes.